# Conditions on $f$,$g$ such that $\int f(x) - g(x)\,\mathrm{d}x$ converges given $f \sim g$

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Let $f$, and $g$ be two functions. I am trying to study under what conditions the integral
$$
    \int_C f(x) - g(x)\,\mathrm{d}x
$$
converges. Where $C$ is some open, half open or closed interval.
The meaning of $g \sim f$ is that if $\lim_{x \to c} f(x)/g(x) =1$ then
$f \sim g$ when $x$ approaches $c$. Naturally questions that arise are what choices for what $c\in C$ one must choose in order to assure convergence. And does $f$ and $g$ need to be monotone increasing functions? An example is given below
$$
    \int_1^\infty \frac{x}{x+1} - \sqrt{\frac{x-1}{x+1}\,}\ \mathrm{d}x
    = 2\log 2 - 1 
$$
Here $f \sim g$ for $x\to\infty$, and both functions are monotonously increasing and the integral converges.
The same holds for Stirrlings formula, but from my meager attempts this integral diverges. Eg
$$
    \int_1^\infty \Gamma(x+1) - \sqrt{2\pi x}\left(\frac{x}{e}\right)^x\,\mathrm{d}x
$$ 
seems to tend of slowly to infinity. I do not quite understand why

*What restrictions is necessary on $f$, $g$ and $c$ for an integral of the form $\int_C f - g $ to converge  given that $f \sim g$ when $x \sim c\in C$?*

Comment: What does $x\sim c$ means?